# Why does my textured object appear black in the viewport in 2.8?

Tags: texturing

Does anyone know how to solve?
I can no longer apply texture.[image]

Comment: Change the Viewport Shading (the 4 circles at the top-right of the viewport) from "Look Dev" mode to "Render Preview", and make sure Cycles renderer is selected (not EEVEE). If that works, then your graphic card may be too old to support EEVEE.  If that doesn't work, then delete your scene and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Check the alpha of the material. If it's on opaque but with alpha value 0, it appears black.
This happened to me when imported models with materials already applied.

Another possibility is trying to delete the material and create a new one again.

Answer (score 0):

Material output node can be specific to one of the renderers.
Without a matching output you'll get a black object.
[image]
It's also possible that your graphics card cannot handle the renderer.

Answer (score 0):

You Can also Solve this problem by updateing you graphics driver